# Remove certain part of Posted value with php

Tags: php

Hello everyone im trying to retrieve data from a form with a POST request.
This data is posted into another website. 
On the website where the data is created i have a text field called website. The data filled in this field goes to the other website where the data is collected. Now i want to exclude the 'www' part. for example if the user enters www.hello.nl i want to receive hello.nl only.

What i tried:

```
function website () {
$str = $_POST['billing_myfield12'];
echo chop($str,"www");
}
// end remove www

// prepare the sales payload
$sales_payload = array(
    'organization_id' => $organization_id,
    'contact_id' => $contact_id,
    'status' => 'Open',
    'subject' => $_product->post_title." ".website(), <----- here i call it
```

This is not working. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or specifically [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to trim way the `www.` on the left side. Please don't forget the `.` after `www`.

```
echo ltrim($str, "www.");
```

**Sample Code**

```
echo ltrim("www.hello.nl", "www."); // hello.nl
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/bqMY7X**

---

Looks like there are side effects with the above code. Let's go with the traditional `str_replace` method:

```
echo str_replace("www.", "", $str);
```

Also, we are sure that it should replace only from the first characters. So, we need to use a `preg_replace` instead, making it replace from the start.

```
echo preg_replace("/^www\./g", "", $str);
```

Verified the above code with: https://regex101.com/r/dv8N6d/1

Comment: Because seriously it's wrong. trim uses a character list.

Comment: I have no idea who did that but you got my upvote and accept, since this is a very good answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks. Just wanted to know why PeeHaa doesn't approve it. I am happy to correct it.

Comment: Does OP really want to remove `www.` in `example.www.com`?

Comment: @Kevin Would you like to answer ^ that one?

Comment: @PeeHaa I have also proposed another regex based solution.

Comment: Yeah, i got one more thing will this work: str_replace("http://"&&"www.", "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])

Comment: @Kevin Nice, but why `&&`?

Comment: I'm a very simple man haha, it means "and" so i thought it would do http and(&&)  www

Comment: @Kevin LoL. Whatever, as it works for you, I am happy!

Comment: @Kevin To make that work, you need `str_replace(array("http://", "www.", "https://"), "", $_POST['billing_myfield12'])` - like this. Sorry didn't understand your question.